# Prevent LQP review comments being moved when answer is converted to comment

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, convert-to-comment

Something I've noticed on several sites recently is that when a moderator converts a non-answer to a comment the automatic comments from the low quality posts review are moved along with it. The following [Magento question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/169812/magento-2-how-to-show-layered-navigation-on-home-page) is an example and I think it's confusing for most users that wouldn't know why it has occurred to have these comments in response to their question:

---

[image: Example converted comments]

I can't think of a valid reason those comments should ever be retained so could something be added to prevent it? I did flag both as "no longer needed" but both were declined, I guess it wasn't obvious to the moderator they were now attached to a question and they thought I was objecting to the review.

Comment: Well, there is a checkbox to  "move comments too" by default unchecked. I usually remove the comments that I do not want to be moved and then move the rest which usually aren't any.

Comment: @lois6b that's odd - I assumed it must be on by default because I've seen this quite a few times now maybe some mods always click it on without checking what the comments are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a ♦ moderator chooses to convert an answer to a comment, he/she will get the **option** to convert the comments under the answer as well or not, and as @lois6b notes, it's **off** by default. They could have fat-fingered this instance; and even if they would do this regularly I'd rather ask them (kindly) to pay a *little* more attention than to spend developer time on this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'd always assumed it must be on by default so next time will stick with a custom flag to make it clearer the comment(s) have been moved incorrectly to under a question.

Comment: Good idea. When processing comment flags, moderators don't see the entire post so it's not always clear at first sight what's going on.